# Reactive Spring demanding return after flatMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm getting a IDE error of "Missing return statement" although I really want to put a "then" after the flatMap.

The repository.findById return a Flux.

The setParent is a bean update.

The repository.save is from the ReactiveCrudRepository:  Mono save(S entity)

Why am I being asked for a return? Why can't I use a then() after this?

```
private Mono<Void> runThreeThings(Batch batch) {
  return repository.findById(batch.getId())
    .flapMap(doc -> {
      doc.setParent(SOME_PARENT_ID);
      repository.save(doc)
}) //  <-- this is where I'm getting a "Missing return statement" error. Why?

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because flatmap has as parameter a function that need a return (object extends Mono)
in your case you need to return a mono and solution will be.

```
        private Mono<Void> runThreeThings(Batch batch) {
        return repository.findById(batch.getId())
                .flapMap(doc -> {
                    doc.setParent(SOME_PARENT_ID);
                    return repository.save(doc);
                });
```

Comment: I'm not interested in the results of this save(). I really need to save() and then start another Flux  - I thought I could do so with a ".then(). after this. I think a map() is useless here - perhaps something like an async foreach()?

Comment: if you dont return the save the save will never be called because it will never be subscribed.
you can do it even with returning another mono and than use .then() but the save will be never called